# Test for Require statement in Truffle

Tags: truffle, require, test

I wrote a function that generate a key value.
the function codes is here

```
   mapping(string => bool) processedHash;
   mapping(uint   => bool) HashList;

function generateHash(uint256 _mintAmount, string memory _refNumber) onlyWhitelistAdmin whenNotPaused public returns(bool){
    require(processedHash[_refNumber] == false,'This transaction already processed');
    CreateKey memory cK = CreateKey({
    mintAmount:_mintAmount,
    ReferenceNumber:_refNumber});
    uint _Hash = uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(cK.mintAmount, cK.ReferenceNumber)));
    require(HashList[_Hash] == false,'This hash already generated.');
    HashList[_Hash] = true;
    processedHash[_refNumber] = true;
    return true;
    }
```

if generated a key before by a reference number, the key mustn't generate there for first require must run in the function and then the transaction must revert.

also I wrote this test in truffle:

```
const assertLib = require('truffle-assertions');
...

it('should not generate the hash for same reference number', async()=>{
  actions.generateHash.call(100, '123', {from: accounts[0]});
  await assertLib.reverts(actions.generateHash.call(100, '123', {from: accounts[0]}));

  });
```

Truffle can't catch the require statement. And truffle giving this output to me

`AssertionError: Did not fail`

how can I catch this require statement? or how can I write test for the function?

thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    it('should not generate the hash for same reference number', async()=>{
        actions.generateHash.call(100, '123', {from: accounts[0]});
        await assertLib.reverts(actions.generateHash.call(100, '123', {from: 
        accounts[0]}));

     });
```

In the above test statement you have specified `generatehash.call()` **.call** is used to read state variables, due to the use of **.call** the first call to `generateHash` did not make any state changes as a result of which the second call is not reverting, try this...

```
    it('should not generate the hash for same reference number', async()=>{
        const receipt = await actions.generateHash(100, '123', {from: accounts[0]});
        console.log('Receipt: ', receipt); // For your reference
        await assertLib.reverts(actions.generateHash(100, '123', {from: 
        accounts[0]}));

     });
```

The assertion will pass in this case.